# In Islam is there another universe other than ours?

Tags: universe

Does the Qur'an mention another universe?

Comment: Define "having shirk thoughts"?

Comment: Hm, would this be considered a matter of believing things about the ghaib (unseen)? If so, what is the ruling concerning belief about the ghaib that doesn't contravene explicit texts, but is also not supported by them?

Comment: Why would it be shirk?

Comment: Not sure what your definition of a 'universe' is. In Islam there are 7 heavens under each sky. We live in the seventh heaven and everything we see/observe is part of this heaven or universe. Hope this helps you in pursuit of the Truth. Note: Paradise & Heaven are two different concepts in Islam.

Answer (score 2):

Allah refers himself as the **lord of the worlds** in the Quran which indicates that there might be other universes out there. He said in the Quran:

> He is the Living (One): There is no god but He: Call upon Him, giving
>   Him sincere devotion. Praise be to Allah, Lord of the Worlds! --
>   (40:65)

We don't know much about that because such details is not provided in the Quran or sahih hadiths.

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

> "So He decreed them as seven heavens in two days, and He revealed in every heaven its Command. And We have adorned the lowest heaven with lamps(i.e Stars), and (set Angels) preserving them. That is the determining of The Ever-Mighty, The Ever-Knowing." 41:12

In another verse(which I couldn't found at the moment), Angels for them to PHYSICALLY come to our universe , our sky will have to crack open. Otherwise, we live in different places and I believe each one has its own law of physics etc.

Now you might consider putting your trust on God as the devils are all out pushing people to Doubt.

Answer (score -2):

Has not you seen the 1st or 2nd ayat of quran: "alhamdu li llahi rabbi lgalamin" - "Praise be to Allah, Lord of the Worlds," - http://www.islamawakened.com/quran/1/2/default.htm ? http://corpus.quran.com/wordbyword.jsp : l-ʿālamīna of the universe N – genitive masculine **plural** noun.